# Docker - Share UFS data

Tags: commit, snapshot, docker

I love the idea of separating my data into a data-container and keeping my application in an "application container" for various reasons. However, it seems that to share data between containers, you need to use volumes which are not kept within the UFS, and hence will not be stored in any commits you perform on the data container. This is advertised as an advantage due to lower overheads, but has the major drawback of not being able to take snapshots through the use of commit.

**Is there a way to force a volume to be held within the UFS?** Or perhaps there is a workaround that shares data from within containers without the use of volumes. Both situations would mean I can take snapshots of the data (this also means that snapshots are incremental which is an added bonus). For now, all I can think of is trying to mount data within the data container through an NFS export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to snapshot a volume, because by essence, volumes are kept out of the copy-on-write storage. However, this might change in the future, since it's becoming a frequent request.

If you really need that feature in the short term, you could bind-mount a host volume which would itself be snapshot-able. E.g., you could mount a BTRFS filesystem on `/btrfs` on the host, then have a `/btrfs/data` subvolume, and then do something like `docker run -v /btrfs/data:/var/data …` to bind-mount that subvolume in the container.

Comment: Unfortunately there is some important context that I did not mention in the question. I want to be able to do this on VPS hosts where I cannot partition the drives with my own filesystems, hence searching for a way to snapshot data with docker or any other tool. If there is a way to create a snapshottable filesystem within a an existing filesystem that would probably do the trick....

Comment: Wouldn't a volume mounted within the UFS be equivalent to a directory?

Comment: @Programster You can create new mountable btrfs volume in a file in your existing filesystem. Then you can do as jpetazzo suggests. See this gist for info how to setup btrfs volume: https://gist.github.com/zahradil/8800421

Comment: @Jiri thanks that sounds like exactly what I want. I have not looked into btrfs before. I am only worried about "...it's still considered experimental." [https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Is_btrfs_stable.3F], so I will have to perform some more research/tests.

Comment: You could also use LVM. If you cannot partition the drives, you will have to use loop devices (i.e. "fake" partitions on top of files), which is not great for performance; but if you really need the snapshots, it's better than nothing!